# Read xml file in SpringBoot

Tags: xml, spring, file, resources, inputstream

I cannot read file in SpringBoot application

 I have tried all the possiblities from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access

 Ofcourse none of the solutions works.


 I have searched any solution on Stack, but none of the subject has resolved answer that would work for me.


 File, InputStreams result always null values.


[image]

 data structure looks like above.

```
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("data.xml");
            return levelXmlWorker.unMarshal(inputStream);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

here the inputStream is null

```
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(new URL(url));
```

here also file is null - but as I have read - it the File cannot be created from inside jar ... ???

```
 InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("data.xml").getInputStream();
```

here inputStream is null :)


Only the absolute path works - obviously it is no solution.


 Is there any Working solution to read files in Spring?

 I can't believe that it isn't possible.


 I think that the **resources** folder is the right place to put files, isn't it?

 but I guess that is has to be fou\nd in the .jar file ... how?

 please solutions... with code exampe...


 Thanks

Comment: Stuff in the `src/main/resources` isn't a file you can only load it as a resource, a `ClassPathResource` to be exact. All the others resolving to File won't work as it isn't a `java.io.File`. The `java.io.File` needs to be an actual resource on the file system, if it is inside a jar that isn't the case.

Comment: Sure, but it produce null aswel ;)

Comment: Then you either haven't the resource in the classpath or you are trying to read it as a file (which won't work because it isn't a afile).

Comment: Looking at your snippet prefix with a `/` as you are trying to load it from the root of the classpath not relative. So use `new ClassPathResource("/data.xml").getInputStream()`. If that doesn't work, have you kicked of your build? So it is in the target folder instead of only the sources?

Comment: it seems I don't have resource in the classpath :/

Comment: `src/main/resources` is the default root of the classpath for non java based resources (like property files, xml etc). So that is the right location. However when running stuff gets copied to the `target` folder and java gets compiled. This is also the location that is used by Intellij (normally) to read from when using classpath based resources. I suspect something is wrong with that (not using the proper directory, not compiling etc.). So you might want to try and re-import the project see if that helps.